# Attempts to write a colon character (":") to a Properties file result in the character being escaped

Tags: java, properties, escaping

In my application, I attempt to write a URL string out to a property file. Of course, since it is a URL, it contains a colon (`:`).

I noticed that when I call `obj.setProperty("key","value")`, it escapes the colon with a backslash, passing `\:` instead.

Here is some code that reproduces the behavior:

```
String url="http://google.co.in";
Properties p=new Properties();
FileOutputStream o=new FileOutputStream("abc.properties");
p.setProperties("testurl",url);
p.store(o,null);
o.close();
```

Why is this happening? Does the Properties class automatically escape certain characters when attempting to write them? Which characters are they?

Comment: This is the standard encoding used by `Properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class's [store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) method API. It says the characters `#, !, =, and :` are saved with escaping backslash.

> The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a
>   preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.

If you read the saved file back with [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) method in Properties class, there is **no** problem. If not, you'll have to write your own custom code to escape these characters while loading.

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal behavior of the class.
Read the javadocs for that:[Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

It says:

> Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes

The colon is one of these characters.